# Detection of button press during animation

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, uibutton

I am using the following code to build a simple scaling effect of a button to build a simple game. 
I want the user to touch to button that leads to something within the scaling period. If they can't touch it within that period then some other things happen.

But using below code, the button only able to detect the touch after the animation complete. Which i don't really wants. I want it able to be detected during the animation. What code should I use in order to get this right?

Thanks

```
-(void) start{
hit1= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[hit1 addTarget:self action:@selector(rolebutton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[hit1 setFrame:CGRectMake(575, 255, 45, 45)];
hit1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;

[hit1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"roles.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[hit1 setExclusiveTouch:YES];


hit1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01);
[self.view addSubview:hit1];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     hit1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
                     hit1.alpha = 1;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     if (finished)
                     {

                         [hit1 removeFromSuperview];


                         NSLog(@"customView Displayed .....");

                     }
                 }];
```

}

```
-(void) rolebutton:(UIButton*) sender{
    NSLog(@"hit");



}/*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the animation option `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction`.

```
-(void) start{
hit1= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[hit1 addTarget:self action:@selector(rolebutton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[hit1 setFrame:CGRectMake(575, 255, 45, 45)];
hit1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;

[hit1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"roles.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[hit1 setExclusiveTouch:YES];


hit1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01);
[self.view addSubview:hit1];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^{
                     hit1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
                     hit1.alpha = 1;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     if (finished)
                     {

                         [hit1 removeFromSuperview];


                         NSLog(@"customView Displayed .....");

                     }
                 }];
```